# Call Recording app for Android, throwing exception

Tags: android, record, mediarecorder

When I run the following code in Emulator, call startes and when call is disconnected it shows NullPointerException when the stop function is called and the output is an empty file when used VOICE_CALL as audiosource. But works when I give VOICE_UPLINK as the audiosource (still the nullpointer exception is there). When I run it in device, it shows FileNotFound exception and Permission Denied as soon as the number is dialed. But I have given required permissions in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

I got the code from here and there from internet only. The one I made was a complete disaster.. The complete class code:

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
PhoneStateListener listener; 
TelephonyManager telephony;
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    listener = new PhoneStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            switch(state)
            {

               case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "OFFHOOK");        
                    StartRecording();
                    break;
               case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                   Log.d("DEBUG", "IDLE");        
                    StopRecording();
                   break;
               case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                   Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING");
                   break;
            }

        }

        public void StartRecording(){

             recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
             recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
             recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
             recorder.setOutputFile(this.getFullSdPath());

             try {
                recorder.prepare();
                Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "Prepared");
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "ERR 1");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "ERR 2");
            }

            recorder.start();   // Recording is now started
            Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "Start Recording");
        }

        public void StopRecording(){

             recorder.stop();          
             recorder.release();
             recorder = null;
             Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "Stop Recording");
        }

        public String getFullSdPath(){
            File sdCard = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()    + "/RecordMyVoice");
            if (!sdCard.exists()) {
                sdCard.mkdir();
            }
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/RecordMyVoice/",new Date().getTime()+".mp4");
            System.out.println("Full path of record sound is : "+file.getAbsolutePath());
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        }           
    };          
    telephony.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);           
}
    }
```

Am i doing something wrong? I've heard that a call recording app cannot be made that easily in Android.

Comment: Have you given the SDCard support while creation of AVD? And, the Size?

Comment: yes! size 100mb.. the file is created. But empty. When I give audio source as VOICE_UPLINK it works but still gives the nullpointerexception

Comment: Did you check that in Device?

Comment: yea.. in device filenotfound error comes with a note saying permission denied. sony ericsson live

Comment: [Have you seen this before?](http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/) Have a look that that. Its just record the voice basically with sample code. Just try this once. And, integrate this code into your project.